# Does a 303 status code pass page rank?

Tags: seo, redirects, 303-redirect

I'm doing an audit for a client who has a 303 redirect on his site from: `example.com` to `example.com/en/`.

I personally would have used a 301 redirect, but I want to know if a 303 passes page rank the same as a 301, if there are any circumstances where I should use a 303, and whether or not I should suggest switching it.

Comment: Why would a 301 better in this instance?

Comment: @w3d Because I know it works

Comment: @w3d Matt Cutts has also said 301s do pass some link juice but not all

Comment: My query about whether a 301 was "better", wasn't necessarily to do with PageRank, but whether a "Moved Permanently" status is really preferred? Do you really want to tell the source of the request (possibly a search engine) that the domain root should not be referenced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Does a 303 pass PageRank like a 301?**

I don't know, but I can devise an approach to your problem based on what I do know. Specifically:

- I know from Google sources that a 301 will pass PageRank and anchor text
- For the purposes of getting a user from `example.com` to `example.com/en/`, both 301 and 303 give the same result

**So should you recommend switching it?**

If passing PageRank is a concern, there's a good argument to use a 301 instead: we know it passes PageRank, and using it doesn't harm functionality, whereas we *don't* know what Google will do with a 303.

Also, a lot of search engine behaviour can be inferred from the specifications of the technology they use and work with. The specification for the 303 states that *"The new URI is not a substitute reference for the originally requested resource"*. So the destination of the redirect is not a substitute for the original: that suggests to me that a search engine might treat it more like a temporary redirection than a permanent one.

**When should you use a 303?**

The specification states that it's intended for forms, which is a very specific intention. I certainly can't think of any other uses that would fit the crux of that specification (quoted above).

Comment: I have a [related question about 303 errors appearing in GWT here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/58563/why-google-webmaster-tools-list-http-status-303-as-crawl-error) Did you maybe experience this too?

Answer (score 0):

A 303 status code does not pass/flow page rank. The w3 status 303 definition can be found at [link](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Example:

Page A 303 redirects to Page B

Title: Page B

URI: Page A

Meta Description: Page B

The page rank of Page A does not pass to Page B.

Comment: I think I saw this exact answer on another websites. Bad form! Besides, the answer on that page suffered from small sample size.